# SQL Server doesn't show the server properties option

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I have a server and a database on Azure and I connected it to SQL Server Management Studio 2017. I want to allow remote connection to my server but I can't get into the "server properties". I'm on free trial on Azure, and the firewall is on with "allow access to Azure services" with my IP on the whitelist.

On right click, the "properties" option doesn't appear

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you mean Azure SQL, you don't have a server so you don't have server properties. You have a *database* that runs on a Microsoft server along with other databases. If you mean SQL Server on an Azure VM, you'll have to ask whoever set it up - perhaps they didn't add you as a sysadmin

Comment: It may work with Azure SQL Instances! see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-managed-instance-general-purpose-tier-general-availability/

Comment: A server with Azure SQL Database has a logical server so server properties are not applicable.

Comment: Hi Jose,  does my answer helped you? Then could you please  mark or vote it?Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

This option is for SQL Server instance not for Azure SQL Database instance.

Azure SQL Database instance is remote database in cloud, you don't need to set it since you have set the special firewall.

If  you don't create the firewall rule, you can not connect to the Azure SQL DB.
[image]

The Azure document said that: A firewall rule is required to connect from other Azure resources and from on-premises resources.

Reference: [Server-level IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule).

We can think that set firewall rule is equivalent to set SQL Server remote connection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then if you do all that, how can you access the *Properties* Option ?, because I want to add another administrator account